# Traffic stops after some minutes via VPN gateway between vnet and on premise machines and then starts again

Tags: vpn, azure, routing, connection

I have a on prem network (192.168.100.0/24) and a vnet (10.0.0.0/16). On prem a Fritzbox 7490 connects with ipsec policy based connection to the VPN gateway in azure. Connection is up and running, no breaks in logfiles.

Now I started a vm in the vnet and it pings to on prem machines successfully. BUT after some minutes, the ping fails and i get a timeout. After another 5 or so minutes the ping is successful again. Then the game starts from the beginning and it fails/succeeds/fails/succeeds and so on, always after around 5min.

Any hints where to look at and how to fix this? I failed in diagnostics, I have no clue..

Answer (score 0):

I can only confirm the same behaviour with a recently built tunnel in the last week of Dec 2020.

The on-prem endpoint is a Meraki MX84.

I rebuilt the Virtual Network Gateway in Azure and on the Meraki as a troubleshooting step; same behaviour.

EDIT: I adjusted phase2 timeout to 28800 from 3600 and the results are positive! I can ping continually now.